# Angular/2 - redirect from external site loses query parameters in Hash URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using a Hash URL in my NG/2 application. Authentication is via a separate service. When I wish to signin I redirect to the service as follows:

```
https://signon.myauth.com?redirect=http://example.com
```

After successful authentication I am redirected back to the domain identified by the "redirect" query parameter with a refreshToken such as:

```
http://example.com?refreshToken=123
```

The problem is the URL is rewritten by NG/2 to read

```
http://example.com/#/
```

and I have lost the query parameters. I appreciate there must be an easy fix I'm just stuggling to find it.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code where the redirect is being processed?

Comment: You could probably try it with the hash included in the redirect: `https://signon.myauth.com?redirect=http://example.com/#/`